Pathologies with Product Ideal $I \cdot J $
Let $R$ be an unitary, commutative, Noetherian ring and $I, J$ two ideals.
The product ideal $I \cdot J$ is defined as
$$  I \cdot J:=\{\sum_i^n a_i \cdot b_i \mid a_i\in I,b_i\in J\}$$
note we allow the finite sums as an ideal is by definition closed with respect addition. Especially the "bête" version
$$  (IJ)^b:=\{a \cdot b \mid a \in I,b \in J\}$$
would due to above reasons be not even an ideal, just a subset of $R$.
But, it's easy to see that if $I$ or $J$ would be principal ideal, then indeed $I \cdot J$ and $(IJ)^b$ coinside.
Question: Is it really an if and only if condition? Especially I worry about the "only if": Can it be proved that if $I$ and $J$ are both not principal and not annihilate each other, then neccessarily $I \cdot J \neq (IJ)^b$ ( as sets); equivalently, latter is not an ideal.
Pondering about a conterexample, I came up with ideals
$$\mathrm{Ann}_R(I) :=\{ a \in R \mid a \cdot I = 0 \} $$
ie those annihilated by $I$. I think ( it should be clear) that if $J + \mathrm{Ann}_R(I) /\mathrm{Ann}_R(I) $ is principal as ideal of $R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(I) $ (...the case interchanged roles for $I$ and $J$) then we have also $I \cdot J =(IJ)^b$.
Subsequently question: Is this the only pathology withcan happen? Or, assume we exclude that either $J + \mathrm{Ann}_R(I) /\mathrm{Ann}_R(I) $ or $I + \mathrm{Ann}_R(J) /\mathrm{Ann}_R(J) $ is prinipal, does then neccessarity hold that  $I \cdot J \neq (IJ)^b$?

What you write as $I^A$ is called the annihilator of $I$ (not "those annihilated by $I$"). Usual notation is $\mathrm{Ann}({}_RI)$ or $\ell$-$\mathrm{Ann}(I)$ for the left annihilator, $\mathrm{Ann}(I_R)$ or $r$-$\mathrm{Ann}(I)$ for the right annihilator, and $\mathrm{Ann}(I)$ for their intersection.

@ArturoMagidin: ok, but feel free in context of this question to assume $R$ to be commutative, so not to distinguish between ring and left ideals

I don't think "feel free" is accurate. It seems to me you are definitely working in the commutative setting, so that should be stated not as an invitation, but as an assumption. In any case, I am pointing out that the notion exists, has standard notation, and that you should use it instead of inventing your own (in addition to misusing "annihilated by $I$" instead of "annihilator of $I$").
